# Ignore $ in first of commands

Tags: bash, terminal

How can I write a function that Bash ignores `$` in first of commands? I want this because sometimes when I paste a command from web it includes a `$` in first character.

`$ ls` should do `ls` or `$ grep 'foo'` should do `grep 'foo'`.

This will not work because `$` is not a valid function name.

```
function $ {
   ...
}
```

Comment: don't copy it to start with? that `$` is used to indicate the shell prompt.

Comment: @MarcB I'm too lazy to do that. I prefer to write a program and make my life easier

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a file called `$` somewhere on your `$PATH`, e.g. in `~/bin`:

```
cd ~/bin
cat <<'EOF' > \$
#!/bin/sh
"$@"
EOF
```

Make it executable:

```
chmod 755 \$
```

And enjoy the madness:

```
$ ls -l
total 92
-rwxr-xr-x 1 thomas thomas    13 Jan  3 19:09 $
$ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ ls
total 92
-rwxr-xr-x 1 thomas thomas    13 Jan  3 19:09 $
```

Comment: +1 nice idea. You should use `"$@"` though, to properly handle arguments with whitespace. I thought a function would be  better than a script, but bash disallows `$` as a function name.

Comment: Another tip: put single quotes around the first heredoc delimiter. That effectively single quotes the entire heredoc and you won't have to escape the variables: `cat <<'EOF' >'$'`

Comment: Thanks! I learned something today :) I actually searched (briefly) to see if this was possible somehow, but y'know, bash manpage...